# how can I make my table view controller scrollable, so the user can swipe it up from the bottom of the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, storyboard

I am writing a `Swift` application, currently I have the storyboard open and I have a `UIViewController` with two elements: `UIImageView` and `TableViewController`, placed one below the other:

[image]

As you may see, the table view controller does not cover the image and is half-visible. 
I want to apply my constraints so that when user swipes it up - the table view controller covers part of the photo:

[image]

and then he will be able to scroll the table further down.

The table itself is dynamically filled with cells, so sometimes it has 10 cells, and sometimes less.

Can you help me and tell me how can I do that so that when user swipes the table view up - first it moves the whole component up and then scrolls the table inside of it?

My inspiration is periscope app, where when you watch the video, the first screen looks like this:

[image]

but when you swipe up the white component - it covers 80% of the screen and user is able to scroll the content that's inside:

[image]

Comment: Try to add `tableView.isScrollEnabled = true`

Answer (score 1):

This link [https://medium.com/@dineshk1389/pull-down-table-views-e33d4c85018b#.c9havwadt] might be useful.

It provides almost the same functionality that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So I think you need to do two different things here.

The first is to enable scrolling in the tableview, as Rashwan noted above. That will handle the case where the number of items is larger than the table, even if it's "scrolled into view". However, you may wish to turn this off when you have the table "down". My question here is what scrolling will look like when only a bit of the table is on-screen. You'll just have to try it

The second part is just to move the table up and down. Add a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to the view to do this, [here](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-gesture-recognizers/) is a tutorial. Don't bother resizing the table or anything, simply change it's Y value and it should all just work. I do things like this in my apps, where the view is offscreen or hidden and then just move it into the display and off again instead of open/close.

Be sure you always make the various Y values relative to your subview - don't assume absolute values or it will go wonky when you change screen sizes.